# Find a matrix M that rotates vector A to the same direction and sense of vector B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, matrix-equations, rotations

Let $M$ be a matrix, $A$ and $B$ be vectors of the same dimension $n$, $A\cdot B$, their dot product and $k$ a scalar.

Given the $a_1...a_n$ coordinates of A and $b_1...b_n$ coordinates B, I'm trying to find the $n \times  n$ cofficients of the matrix $M$ that maps (rotates) $A$ to a vector of the same direction and sense of $B$, while preserving the length of A. In other words, the following conditions must be satisfied:

1. $(M \cdot A) $ = $kB$
2. $|A| = |kB|$

Condition 1 leads to the following system of $n$ equations:
\begin{align*}
    \\
m_{11} . a_1 + m_{12} . a_2 +... m_{1n} . a_n = k.b_1 \\
m_{21} . a_1 + m_{22} . a_2 +... m_{2n} . a_n = k.b_2 \\
&\vdots\\
m_{n1} . a_1 + m_{n2} . a_n + ... m_{nn} . a_n = k.b_n
\end{align*}

While condition 2 adds one equation more:

$\sqrt[2]{a_1^2+a_2^2+...a_n^n} = \sqrt[2]{(k.b_1)^2+(k.b_2)^2+...(k.b_n)^2}$

Which can be rewritten as:

$\sqrt[2]{a_1^2+a_2^2+...a_n^n} = k.\sqrt[2]{[(b_1)^2+(b_2)^2+...(b_n)^2]}$

In other words, with knowledge of values of $A$ and $B$, condition 1 and 2 define an (underdetermined) system of $n+1$ equations and  $n \times n + 1$ variables. How can a solution for this system be found, that is, a matrix M that would satisfy both conditions given A and B?

Comment: What properties do you want $M$ to have? Should $M$ be a rotation matrix (i.e. $M^TM$ is the identity and $\det(M) = 1$)? Is it important for $M$ to be invertible?

Comment: M can be any matrix.I'm looking for a general answer for all possible solutions and one that is easy to compute.

Comment: I suggest that you start by solving this in the case that $A = (1,0,\dots,0)$.

Comment: Choose $v_2,\dots,v_n$ such that $\{\,A,v_2,\dots,v_n\,\}$ is a basis, then let $MA=(|A|/|B|)B$, $Mv_i$ be whatever you like, $i=2,\dots,n$. You could even take $Mv_i=0$ for $i=2,\dots,n$.

Comment: Did that help??

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has abandoned it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I'm sorry, I did not understand your solution. Why should $MA=(|A|/|B|)B$? And what would be the relation of this with the basis?

Comment: From your $|A|=|kB|$ we get $k=|A|/|B|$ (assuming $k\ge0$), then from your $MA=kB$ we get $MA=(|A|/|B|)B$. If you know $Mv$ for all $v$ in a basis, that determines $M$ completely, and gives you enough equations to find all the entries in $M$.